# How to access correct index on Javascript For Loop on Event Handler

Tags: javascript, for-loop, closures, dom-events

I know that this is a common problem but looking at other examples on this site just hasn't seemed to work for me.

I am trying to implement a multi file image upload box that displays the  images to upload before they have been sent to the server.

I am having the common problem of only being able to view the last image that is in the file upload list.

I decided to break the problem into its smallest parts and just output the index of each value in the list to the Javascript console.

But I am only getting the last value of the index. Once I am able to get the correct index value I should be able to also correct the initial problem of not displaying the images to be uploaded.

Here is my code:

```
handleImage(event){

    //this is where I would set up the image to be displayed
    var testFunction = function(res) {
        console.log(res);
    }


    var files = event.target.files;

    for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {


        var fReader = new FileReader();

        //trying to use a closure but not working correctly    
        (function(){

            fReader.addEventListener("load", function () {

                //testFunction(fReader.result);

                testFunction(i);


            });

            fReader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);

        }(i));
    }
}
```

So my question is how do I create the correct closure to capture the correct index value?

Comment: You're calling your closure function with a parameter but you haven't added an argument to it, change it to `(function(i){ ... })(i)` and it should work as expected.

Comment: Note also that if you simply changed the `var i = 0` to `let i = 0` in the loop header you would avoid all these problems, including any need for the IIFE